# Copy a table from one worksheet to another while maintaining column size

Tags: vba, excel

Copy a table from one worksheet to another where the column size from the original worksheet is to be maintained as the new sheet already has a table with smaller sized columns.

```
Dim i, lastRow

lastRow = Sheets("Closed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow

Sheets("Closed").Cells(i, "A").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Misc.Dashboard").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Sheets("Closed").Cells(i, "B").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Misc.Dashboard").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Sheets("Closed").Cells(i, "C").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Misc.Dashboard").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Sheets("Closed").Cells(i, "D").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Misc.Dashboard").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Sheets("Closed").Cells(i, "E").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Misc.Dashboard").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Sheets("Closed").Cells(i, "F").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Misc.Dashboard").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Sheets("Closed").Cells(i, "G").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Misc.Dashboard").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Sheets("Closed").Cells(i, "H").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Misc.Dashboard").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Sheets("Closed").Cells(i, "I").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Misc.Dashboard").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Next i
```

[image: First sheet,table to be copied]

[image: Second sheet, paste table below the table present]

Comment: ever heard of the method xlPasteSpecial? if not try google :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please keep in mind this is not a code service. Please have a look at these pages. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to VB.

Comment: Kindly help me modify the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems you're copying all data from the "Closed" worksheet and adding it to the bottom of the "Misc.Dashboard" Sheet, instead of writing a loop, which becomes very slow if amount of data increases, try to copy the range in one go.

```
Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long

With ThisWorkbook
    With .Worksheets("Closed")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Copy
    End With
    With .Worksheets("Misc.Dashboard")
        .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), .Cells(.Rows.Count, lastColumn).End(xlUp).Offset(1 + lastRow, 0)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteColumnWidths)
        .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), .Cells(.Rows.Count, lastColumn).End(xlUp).Offset(1 + lastRow, 0)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    End With
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you. Although none of the table formatting is being retained i.e borders, highlights, indentation.

Comment: Have a look at the various `pastespcial` options on the msdn site.